# Tweedie index parameters are restricted: why?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, exponential-family, tweedie-distribution

The Tweedie distribution have variance like var(y) = $\phi \mu^p$ for any real p not between 0 and 1.

I read in many places (even wikipedia) that p can take any real value except between 0 and 1.  That seems weird and I don't understand why.
I have read the usual reference which is Jorgensens book the "Theory of Dispersion Models" (page 132) but that makes no sense to me (i can't see why the same argument work for p>3 for instance). 
Can anyone simply explain why p can't be a number between 0 and 1?